# Understanding serial device settings

Tags: serial-port

Please feel free to slap me and send a link if this question has already been answered; I just couldn't find it.  I did search though.

I've been trouble-shooting communication with a serial device.  In looking over lots of documentation, I now understand what the settings for "baud rate," "data bits," "stop bit," and "parity" mean.  But what I can't seem to understand is who (sender or receiver) determines these settings.

Say I have a serial device plugged into my computer.  In my code, I open a connection to the serial port and specify something like 9600,8,E,1.  When I specify these settings, do these get sent to the sending itself, so that it knows how to send the data to my receiver?  Or is it more common for a sender to expect a receiver to comply with strict settings?

The issue I'm having is that I attempted to use "Even" parity, and that resulted in tons of irregular transfer errors.  When I use "Odd" parity, however, those errors go away.  There is also a USB to Serial adapter involved in my set up.  There aren't any transfer errors with Even or Odd parity without the adapter in the middle.  So I'm just having a hard time understanding whether the device itself doesn't support sending with Even parity, or whether the adapter is the thing causing trouble, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Neither, it is entirely up to you to ensure that the settings that the device and the PC uses are the same.  Since you don't seem to know the device settings, you will be much ahead by using a telephone so you can be sure.

Comment: Thanks.  What do you mean by using a telephone?

Comment: Pick one up, dial the number of the company that manufactured the device, ask to talk to somebody in technical support.  They know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I specify these settings, do these get sent to the sending itself, so that it knows how to send the data to my receiver?

No.

To expand on the comment by Hans Passant, both sides of the serial port have to agree on the settings, otherwise they won't talk to each other.  If they don't agree, you will get gibberish data on either side as the hardware will read the data at an incorrect time.  The settings are normally documented in the manual for the device that you are attempting to communicate with.  For example, to communicate with a Cisco router, you will generally use the [following settings](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/dial-access/asynchronous-connections/9321-terminal-settings.html):

```
Bits per sec    :  9600 
Data bits       :     8 
Parity          :  none 
Stop bits       :     1 
Flow control    :  none
```

When you setup the serial port on your side, you must use these same settings, there is no hardware-level handshake between the two devices that determines the speed that they will communicate at.

Sometimes, the format for the serial port settings may be given in a format like the following:

```
9600,8,N,1
```

Which is just shorthand for the above quote(9600 baud, 8 data bits, no parity, 1 stop bit)

In my experience, most devices default to `9600,8,N,1`, the next common serial setting is `115200,8,N,1`

Comment: Very helpful, thanks.  One more point for clarification.  I was testing with "Even" parity.  Using a port sniffer, I discovered that the device's software uses "Odd" parity.  When plugged directly into the serial port on the computer, my data matched up with the data coming from the device's software.  How can this be, if using different Parity settings?  I only started seeing transfer errors using Even parity when using a USB to Serial adapter.  Not even sure where to start trouble-shooting that :)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly could be causing that.  What did you use to do the part sniffing?

Comment: I used Serial Port Monitor from Eltima.  The device's own software sets it to Odd parity, so that's what I'm doing now and there are no errors with or without a USB to serial adapter.  Before, with Even parity, I got no errors without the adapter but many errors with the adapter.  So strange!  Makes me wonder about this adapter.  We'll I'll go ahead and mark this as resolved. If you've got any more ideas or helpful resources beyond Wikipedia on how to better understand parity and all of this, I'd appreciate it. Thanks again!